# Android app to complement my own on-page web chat widget?

Tags: android, chat, push-notifications

I'm thinking about implementing something similar to 'my own on-site web chat widget'. Or more generic, some Q&A solution.

And while I can build the back-end myself (and prefer to), I'd like to use some kind of front-end app that's 3rd party software - preferably open-source. I'm not talking about the widget - but about the "operator app".

I'm looking for an android app that's configurable and has the option to trigger Android notifications near real-time.

Currently my best bet would be an IRC app. Someone posts to my web chat (or Q&A forum) and my back-end relays this post to my own IRC channel. Then: the Android app in question follows that channel and alerts me once people join the chat or post something (and I can immediately react). But I'm not that familiar with IRC.

I don't know if there's an even more lightweight solution. What I'd basically need is a configurable app, that can track (poll or more efficiently) some web resource, trigger an alert, and allow me to react in-app with responses to this update/event/inquiry/post.

Comment: Guess you'll be better off doing that via XMPP. There are plenty of XMPP apps available (line Conversations, which is FOSS and available at F-Droid). So if your back-end feeds to your specific channel which you've subscribed to with your user, you'd get your notification via Conversations. // If that's acceptable, my recommendation would be "Conversations" – but you'd need something in your backend feeding the channel (or addressing your user directly). I've no experience with that part.

Comment: Although I would welcome a little background on why XMPP and not IRC, I found the XMPP Android Client "Conversations" via your post which looks like a polished app and fit for the task. +1 for that!

Comment: The background is: Try finding an IRC client for Android. There are few, but either no longer maintained, having quite special requirements, not being polished – or a combination of that. [See here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_techsites#group_1137) for a list. While Conversations is well maintained, a reference client, polished, feature-rich and all; [see here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_messenger#group_1170) for alternatives. You might also like the [MAXS Suite](http://projectmaxs.org/homepage/) which is built on XMPP.

Comment: Very helpful resources! Thanks @izzy ! +1

Comment: Glad they helped! Would you like me to make that an answer (Conversations as the app you've asked for)? Or would you rather prefer to test first and then [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) with the fitting combination (which would most likely be the better answer)?

Comment: Actually, I'd like to leave it open like that, for a while at least, to attract more input. But at the same time I think all was said, and my question might be a little too vague. Go ahead if you have the time.

Comment: OK, then let's leave it as-is for now. Be welcome to use my hints for writing up an answer. Best luck for a well-fitting solution!